# Errors Notifier for a Ruby command line app

Tags: ruby, command-line

I have a command line application and I would like to have a way to be notified if an error occurs via e-mail. It is a ruby command line app, it runs via a schedule cron job.

Anything that is fairly simple to setup would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/54152/how-to-get-e-mail-from-failed-cron-jobs-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of services that you can use to catch Ruby errors and exceptions. Most of them provide some kind of free package and all of them relay errors via email.

- [Sentry](https://www.getsentry.com/) - free plan for 250 events per day with 7 day history. Email notifications. All you have to do is install [raven-ruby](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby) gem and set `SENTRY_DSN` environment variable provided by Sentry.
- [Honeybadger](https://www.honeybadger.io/) - micro plan for $19/month for 3 apps with 7 day history. You install [honeybadger](https://rubygems.org/gems/honeybadger) gem and environment variable `HONEYBADGER_API_KEY` and you are ready to go. They also send notifications via email.
- [Raygun](https://raygun.io/) - They provide free trail without credit card, emails are also part of their service. You need [raygun4ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/raygun4ruby) gem, instructions to use it with Rails can be found [here](http://raygun.io/raygun-providers/ruby-on-rails).

Other option could be that you log your exceptions into log and then you create another cron job that sends you that daily report?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this here in the hope that the next person that wants to add honeybadger to their app doesn't struggle with the same problem I did. If you're running honeybadger outside of a rails app, you need to start the service explicity.

```
ENV['HONEYBADGER_API_KEY'] = 'abc123'
Honeybadger.start

# Your code here...

Honeybadger.stop
```

If you don't start the honeybadger service, you won't be able to send notifications. I couldn't find anywhere that mentioned this important fact.